# Synching my iPhone 6+ with a iTunes on a new Mac

Tags: itunes, mac, iphone

When I connect my iPhone 6+ to my Mac, iTunes greeted me with a "Set up your iPhone" screen, which offered me the choice of "restoring from backup", and "setting up as a new iPhone" . Please help! I especially do not want to loose my app data. I also use iMazing and it does not have the same problem. I really went the Mac route initially hoping for better compatibility with iTunes but Apple really seems to complicate the use of iTunes totaly unnecessarily. I there a really definitive technical guide for iTunes.

Comment: Is this the first time you've connected this phone to this Mac? Do you have any backup (and if yes, where? other computer, iCloud?).

Comment: No I have connected it before but could not synch without it threatening to delete stuff on my phone-I have a iMazing back-up which iTunes sees

Comment: I used to synch with my windows laptop which I want to retire now but it still is registrred as my main machine